# Is it possible to check a Task is complete by using `task.Id`?

Tags: c#

I am newbie of C#. Is it possible to check if a Task is complete by using `task.Id`?

Comment: There is [`Task.IsCompleted`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.task.iscompleted?view=net-5.0#System_Threading_Tasks_Task_IsCompleted) that you should probably use.

Comment: Not sure if this is what you're trying to do, but If you add the tasks to a list when you create them, you can use `await Task.WhenAny` to address each task as they complete. [See Microsoft's example here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/async/start-multiple-async-tasks-and-process-them-as-they-complete).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Task IDs are assigned on-demand and do not necessarily represent the order in the which Task instances were created.

They have nothing to do with the state of the task.

Answer [source](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/threading/Tasks/Task.cs,1318).